# Java Spring IntelliJ jstl tags doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, jstl

I was trying to do a simple application with Spring using IntelliJ and gradle as a build tool. I did a simple panel with inputs from jstl library, but they are some problems with the server i guess, because browser doesn't show any inputs. That is my first Spring project futhermore I have never worked with IntelliJ and gradle, so there is a possibility that I've made some stupid mistake which i can't work out.

createUser.jsp (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Dodaj usera</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userDTO">
    <h1>Podaj imie: </h1>
    <form:input type="text" path="name" /> <br />
    <h1>Podaj nazwisko: </h1>
    <form:input type="text" path="secondName" /> <br />
    <h1>Podaj nr telefonu: </h1>
    <form:input type="text" path="phoneNumber" /> <br />
    <h1>Podaj e-mail: </h1>
    <form:input type="text" path="eMail" /> <br />
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

controller.java:

```
@Controller
public class Controler {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
String hello(){
    return "hello";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String userFormGet(){
    return "createUser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
String userFormPost(@ModelAttribute("form") @Valid UserDTO userDTO, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "createUser";
    }
    else
        return "redirect:/hello";
}
}
```

configuration.java class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.petkow")
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new  InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")

}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
baseName = 'transport-service'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final'
}
```

Starter class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TransportServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TransportServiceApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

data transmission object class:

```
public class UserDTO {

@NotBlank
@Length(min=2, max=50)
private String name;
@NotBlank
@Length(min=2, max=50)
private String secondName;
@Min(9)
@Max(9)
private long phoneNumber;
@NotBlank
@Email
private String eMail;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
}

public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
}

public long getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(long phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String geteMail() {
    return eMail;
}

public void seteMail(String eMail) {
    this.eMail = eMail;
}
}
```

[result from browser request:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRO0W.png)

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your controller code is slightly wrong. In the get method you are not registering model name. Spring form tag is breaking. This may be the reason for your problem.
Change Controller method like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ModelAndView userFormGet(){
    return new ModelAndView("page","userDTO",new UserDTO());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed it but still the same. Have you got any other ideas what can be wrong? It seems like this three top lines in .jsp file are not properly handled, because I get them back as text in my browser.

Comment: I don't see any other issue. I didn't see the text field in your screen shot also. I assumed that spring form tags are breaking. try this in some other browser.

Comment: Everything is ok when i don't use this tags, i mean when i get pure html. I don't think that there is some issue with browser. I've tried to get this page on three browsers, each returns same.

Comment: Did you mean when you don't put `form:form` tag page comes fine? If that is the case then I strongly feel that issue is with these tags only. I have updated my answer with correct request attribute. try with that.

Comment: Doesn't work too. I mean that all tags are omitted. Also this three top declarations: "<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>" are omitted and returned as a text instead of being handled in some way by the server.